# Magento 1.7.0.2 Filter by multiple categories - SQL Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Refering to
[Magento 1.7 Filter products by multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498556/magento-1-7-filter-products-by-multiple-categories)
I have a new question:

I'am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and the described solutions to filter a product-collection by multiple categories (via AND) does not work for me.

My categorie structure:

- Root

  - cat 1

    - cat 1a
    - cat 1b
  - cat 2

    - cat 2a
    - cat 2b
  - cat 3

A product for example can be in cat 1a, cat 2 and cat 2b at the same time.
It should be listed, if I filter:

- after cat 1a
- after cat 1a & cat 2
- after cat 1a & 2b & 2

It must **not** be visible, if I filter:

- after cat 3
- after cat 1 & cat 1a
- after cat 1a & 2a

My Code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',
            array("finset" => array(53, 46))
        );
```

This gets me a SQL-Error:

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'
SELECT `e`.*, `at_category_id`.`category_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(53, 46, at_category_id.category_id))
```

What I've to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an array in your call:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
     array('finset' => array(53, 46)),
 )
```

Comment: This didn't workk either.
I get again an error: (#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET')
SELECT `e`.*, `at_category_id`.`category_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) WHERE (((FIND_IN_SET(53, 46, at_category_id.category_id))))

Answer (score 0):

After a few days i figuered out a way to reach my goal.
The magic word: custom SQL queries.

Here is a sample of SQL statement (MySQL) to filter all product_ids by multiple categories at once.

```
SELECT a.product_id as entity_id
    FROM catalog_category_product a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.product_id
                  FROM catalog_category_product b
                  WHERE b.product_id = a.product_id and b.category_id = 53)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT b.product_id
                  FROM catalog_category_product b
                  WHERE b.product_id = a.product_id and b.category_id = 46)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT b.product_id
                  FROM catalog_category_product b
                  WHERE b.product_id = a.product_id and b.category_id = 39)
    GROUP BY a.product_id
```

You can repeat the "AND EXISTS ..." til doomsday, if you wanted ;)
This one would filter all products, which are in the categories 53, 46 and 39 at the same time.

You can read more about custom SQL-commands in Magento here:
http://magentotutorials.blogspot.de/2011/07/magento-code-to-run-custom-sql-query.html