# Need product count in magento

Tags: magento

I need to show product count behalf of brand/manufacturer

```
foreach($children as $subCat)
{
  $brand_name = $subCat->getName();
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 
  $products = $products->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$brand_name);
  echo $products->count();
}
```

Comment: does the above function works or it doesnt?

Comment: yeah everything is working fine, echo shows 0 every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If brand is `dropdowon or  Multi Select attribute` then you cannot filter by  `BrandName(That means option name).`
You can filter by Brand Option id:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 
  $products = $products->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$brand_id);
```

if you are using `Catalog Product flat` then you need to Enable manufacturer attribute to `Product Listing`  from Manage attribute >select manufacturer attribute enable attibute to product listing

According to you comment if you want to Product Collection by  two catgories then  try below

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
     array('finset' => $catid),
     array('finset' => $parent_Cat_id))
 )
 ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

More details  in [Magento 1.7 Filter products by multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498556/magento-1-7-filter-products-by-multiple-categories)

Or get all option  list of Manufacture attribute then you can get it option id by  below code

```
$attribute_code = "manufacture";
 $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code);
 $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
foreach($options as $option){ 
// print_r($option) and find all the elements e
cho $option["value"];
 echo $option["label"]; 
}
```

- See more at: http://www.techdilate.com/code/magento-get-attribute-options-of-the-dropdown-type-attribute/#sthash.81mUiz6O.dpuf
  Then get  product Collection filter by option ids

Comment: amit how do i get $brand_id ?? [entity_id] => 980 [parent_id] => 220

Comment: i print an array and i got this entity_id is brand id and i need to know how do i get this

Comment: have a look https://www.notableaccessories.com/index.php/mobile-accessories/appcessories.html

Comment: I have seen  it.   980 is category id and  280 is parent id catgeory

Comment: that's why i am trying to get products count using brand name

Comment: i think i am confusing you, i need list of brands with product count, you can see on given link Versio Mobile have 3 records but its show 2 in the brand